# Is there a rule for taking any function of both parts of an equation or an inequality?

Tags: inequality

1) I have an inequality $f(x)\ge g(x)$.

Can I state (maybe with some stipulations) that for any function h(x) the following holds $$ h(f(x)) \ge h(g(x)) $$

2) I have an equation $f(x) = g(x)$.

Can I state (maybe with some stipulations) that for any function h(x) the following holds $$ h(f(x)) = h(g(x)) $$

What all those stipulations for cases 1 and 2 should be? Are there any limitations on h(x) function (its type, domain, range)?

I feel there shoukld be some general rule, but I am not sure about all correct stipulations about domain/range, etc...

Comment: $1)$ is true for monotone increasing functions $h$. $2)$ is always true (assuming that both expressions are defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point (1): 
Let's assume that the functions $ f(x) $ , $ g(x) $ and $ h(x)$ have domains $D_f $ , $ D_g $ and $ D_h $ respectively and : $$ f(x) \ge g(x) \ \forall x \in D_f \cap D_g $$
(Assume $ D_f \cap D_g \neq \emptyset$)

Before moving it is necessary to write down the domains of the composite functions that appear in the new inequality. Those functions are:$$ h(f(x)) $$ and $$ h(g(x)) $$

By definition the domains of those are $ D_{h \circ f} = \{x \in D_f | \ f(x) \in D_h \}$ and $ D_{h \circ g} = \{x \in D_g | g(x) \in D_h \} $ respectively.

Now you CAN state that: **$$ h(f(x)) \ge h(g(x))\ \forall x\in D_{h \circ f} \cap D_{h \circ g} $$**

*iff* $ \ $i) h(x) is a monotone increasing (strictly or not) function and ii) $ D_{h \circ f} \cap D_{h \circ g} \neq \emptyset $

For the second point (2):

Suppose now h(x) is *any* function with random properties, then you can freely state that if

$$ f(x)=g(x)  \ \ (Equation \ 1) $$

$$ then $$

$$ h(f(x))=h(g(x)) \ \ (Equation \ 2)$$

or in other words $ f(x)=g(x) \Rightarrow  h(f(x))=h(g(x)) \ \ (3)$ as long as $ D_{h \circ f} \cap D_{h \circ g} \neq \emptyset $ .

The above (Equation 3) is always true because of the definition of a function.

However, be careful the equation (1) and (2) might not be equivalent (might not have the same solutions). Equation (3) can become:

$$ f(x)=g(x) \Leftarrow\Rightarrow  h(f(x))=h(g(x)) \ (Equation \ equivalency) $$

if and only if h(x) is a 1-1 function. ($ \forall x,y \in D_h  \Rightarrow h(x) \neq h(y)$)

Comment: Solving any f(x) = g(x) equation I can always apply a 1-to-1 function h(x) to f(x) and g(x) and thus I get an absolutely equivalent equation, I solve it and get all solutions (and only those solutions) for original  f(x) = g(x) equation? Right? So applying a 1-to-1 function I do not have to care about range, domain or anything else? I am trying to make a complete algorithm for equation solving method.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite grasped the significance of (3): as long as $ D_{h \circ f} \cap D_{h \circ g} \neq \emptyset $ .

Comment: @caasdads Thank you for the commend ! I will be happy to elaborate on (3) but unfortunately I am running out of time right now and I want to write a good answer. You will definitely have one until tomorrow.

Cheers!

Comment: @caasdads Imagine if $ D_{h o f} \cap D_{h o g} = 0 $ (That means that the function one the left side is defined on an interval that does not over lap with the domain of the function of the rightside) then, there is no point in considering the equation. Also think it of this way:
It is true that $$ h(f(x)) = h(g(x)) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow h(f(x))-h(g(x)) = 0 $$
Now Let's define the first side as one whole function, say B(x).
You can clearly see that $ D_B = \emptyset $ and this function has not a graph in the x-y plane. Hope that helped! If you still feel frustrated, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For both cases you have to assume that $h$ is defined over at least a subset of the intersection of the codomain of $f$ and $g$, and subsequently limit the domain of $f$ and $g$.

For the first case, you have to assume that $h$ is an increasing function, at least over the common range of $f$ and $g$, otherwise you could have cases in which 
$$h\big(f(x)\big)<h\big(g(x)\big)$$
even if 
$$f(x)\geq g(x)$$
for example let $x,y\in (0,\infty)$ and
$$x> y$$
now if we consider the function $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ defined as
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$
then we have
$$f(x)<f(y)$$

For the second case, if we call $z=f(x)=g(x)$ then is trivial to see that
$$h\big(f(x)\big)=h(z)=h\big(g(x)\big)$$
with no particular restrictions